# Select Specific java version

Tags: deployment, java

If my machine have multiple version of jre installed say jre 5, jre 6 and jre 7. 
Is it possible to force my application to use specific jre (say jre 5) at runtime?

Comment: You can check which JRE was used when starting a program and fail with descriptive message if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: i was wondering when we are able to see list of jre from java control panel(Windows and Mac OSX not sure about Linux), So we may able able to select what version we want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found way to do it. We can allow application to select jre by `javaw -version:"version String"` as given in [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

For Example : javaw -version:"1.6.*"

Answer (score 2):

Launch the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It provides many options for [Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html).

[image: JNLP Runtime Settings]

All the ticked JREs are available for use by JWS launched apps.

Here is how you might select any 1.5 variant in the launch file.

```
<j2se version="1.5" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I have on my computer 3 JDKs. Every JDK has own environment variable

```
%JAVA_HOME_1_5%  
%JAVA_HOME_1_6%  
%JAVA_HOME_1_7%
```

when I want use specific JDK, I set `%JAVA_HOME%` to this variable.
Also I use scripts for using different JDK.  For example, if I want start Jboss using **JDK 6**, I run next script

```
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME_1_6%; 
%JBOSS_HOME%/run.bat
```

If I want execute runnable jar (using **JDK 5**) I run next script

```
%JAVA_HOME_1_5%/bin java MyJar.jar
```

If I want run maven with **JDK 7**, I am using next script

```
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME_1_7%  
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

etc.

So you can use any JDK using env. variables and simple scripts

Answer (score 1):

Run the java in corresponding paths:

usr/local/jdk1.5/bin/java HelloWorld

usr/local/jdk1.6/bin/java HelloWorld

usr/local/jdk1.7/bin/java HelloWorld

etc...

Answer (score 1):

In your running application use

```
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
```

To check which version of Java is being used to run your app. You can throw an exception if it doesn't match what you want.

Comment: *"You can parse out the major version"*  Easier to use the [`java.specification.version`](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.specification.version&format=TSV) (here reports '1.7').

Answer (score 0):

You can force the application by starting it using an absolute path on disk to a specific Java version.

Comment: that wont be possible because i need to select jre before actual application starts.

Answer (score 0):

You generally have to do this before you launch java. Inside a script you can look for the executable of a specific version of java and fail if that jre doesn't exist/isn't in a known location. Then after finding that version of java run your java program with that jre. How to explicitly do this depends on your OS.

Once inside the java program java you can't change versions. Hence java checks for version (inside of a java program) are only useful for quitting before full executing rather than changing to a valid version.